# get HTML from .Net MVC View without actually rendering the view in the browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ActionResult in my controller that I want to send an HTML email from, the body of that email is generated by a view.  Rather than having 2 actionresults methods in my controller can I just get the result of the view when passed my model and avoid it being sent to the browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render a view as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

Comment: I ended up using this solution: http://persistall.com/archive/2007/12/21/asp.net-mvc---renderview-testing-workaround.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[MvcMailer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MvcMailerNuGet.aspx)** is a brilliant little project that supports generating emails using MVC views. It is available as a NuGet package.

In order to render a view to a string instead of response use this code (`relativePath` points to your view file):

```
        var content = string.Empty;
        var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, relativePath, null);
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var context = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view.View, ViewData, TempData, writer);
            view.View.Render(context, writer);
            writer.Flush();
            content = writer.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Api.ControllerContext is System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext and FindView needs System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext...

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the open source [Postal project](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) it's available view NuGet.

> Postal lets you create emails using regular MVC views.

Andrew Davey done a presentation on [Generating email with View Engines](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Andrew-Davey-Going-Postal-Generating-email-with-View-Engines) using Postal at mvcConf 2

Or alternatively [this blog post](http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/) shows you a simple way.

Comment: I believe MVC 4 is not yet supported with Postal