# How to get the view object (System.Web.Mvc.IView)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-views

How can I retrieve a view object in the same project from any controller?

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181260/get-html-from-net-mvc-view-without-actually-rendering-the-view-in-the-browser) suggests using System.Web.Mvc.ViewEngines.Engines.FindView but I can't derive an System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext instance from System.Web.Http.ApiController.

I'm trying to get the view object to call Render on it to get it out as a string.